# how to call batch files from a PowerShell 5.0 script which has white space in the path?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to call a batch file from a PowerShell 5.0 Script. The path for the batch file is :

```
\\192.168.0.1\hde_path\Tools Powershell\abc.cmd
```

So, my path has a white space inside it and I tried to call it in the following way..

```
cmd.exe /c "'\\192.168.0.1\hde_path\Tools Powershell\abc.cmd'"
```

Now, it gives the error:

```
The system can not find the file specified.
```

But, please note:

- This file **abc.cmd** exists in this location.
- I have access to this location.
  Because, I can run this abc.cmd file via command prompt without any issues.

Again, when I am putting abc.cmd file in some path where the path does  not have any space in it, e.g. : \192.168.0.1\hde_path\Tools\abc.cmd and I call it using the following command, it runs perfectly fine.

```
cmd.exe /c '\\192.168.0.1\hde_path\Tools\abc.cmd'
```

Please help!

Comment: only double quotes should do it `cmd.exe /c "\\192.168.0.1\hde_path\Tools\abc.cmd"`

Comment: @JamesC. Thanks for the quick reply. But, I would like to remind you that the path you have used in your comment does not have any space in it. But I need to call a batch file which has a white space in it.

Comment: @SrijaniGhosh, neither does yours in your last example; anyway, `cmd` uses `"` for quotation, `'` are just considered normal characters...

Comment: @aschipfl .. I know my last examples does not contain white spaces. Because, I was writing an example that without white spaces the code is working fine. and with white spaces it is not. Please read the whole question. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: My comment was still the correct answer, I just copied the wrong path from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
cmd.exe /c '\\192.168.0.1\hde_path\Tools Powershell\abc.cmd'
```

or

```
cmd.exe /c "\\192.168.0.1\hde_path\Tools Powershell\abc.cmd"
```

Should work.

Answer (score 3):

Double quotes works for me

```
cmd.exe /c "\\127.0.0.1\c$\temp\Test Folder\test.cmd"
```